# Is it possible to root an Android device without it restarting/rebooting?

Tags: java, android, rooted-device

Long story short, there's a security issue with my application that is only valid if the device can be rooted without my application being closed, which is why I am researching whether that is possible or not.

A lot of guides mention that a reboot is often required, however, I can't find any concrete evidence stating whether it is always or often required, which is why I've come here to ask this question.

Comment: Letting aside that this is not a programming question at all, you’re assuming that the device couldn’t be rooted already when your application is started?

Comment: @Holger I'm preventing users with rooted devices from using the application, but I am wary of a user logging in on a non-rooted device, then have their device stolen and rooted by a malicious third party without exiting from the application and then that malicious party running a memory dump of the application.

Comment: I'll agree with Holger that the question as phrased is off-topic. More importantly, you are letting "rooted device" do a lot of heavy lifting, where that term can mean different things to different people. For most people, the *point* of rooting a device is for that state to survive a reboot. In your case, rooting isn't even your concern. Your concern is a "malicious party running a memory dump of the application". That requires being able to run processes with superuser privileges, but does not necessarily imply "rooting" as the term tends to be used in Android.

Comment: As to whether an adversary can potentially run a memory dump of your application without triggering a reboot, you should assume that the answer is yes.